# Why does a compile error occur in AnnotatedElement.getAnnotation()?

Tags: java

One segment of codes in book "Effective Java" is as follows:

```
static Annotation getAnnotation(AnnotatedElement element, String annotationTypeName) {
    Class<?> annotationType = null; // Unbounded type token
    try {
        annotationType = Class.forName(annotationTypeName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
    }
    return element.getAnnotation(annotationType.asSubclass(Annotation.class));
}
```

but getAnnotation() has a compile error in my eclipse:

Bound mismatch: The generic method getAnnotation(Class) of type AnnotatedElement is not applicable for the arguments (Class). 
 The inferred type capture#13-of ? extends Annotation is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

The version of my jdk is 1.7

[image: image of location in code]

Comment: The code compiles fine on JDK 1.8, so it must be something in JDK 1.7 that's causing the issue then...

Comment: Time to upgrade to Java 8 I think.  Java 7 was end-of-life some time ago.   Alternatively just use an explicit cast, and then suppress the warning.

Comment: Try `Class<Annotation> sub = annotationType.asSubclass(Annotation.class); return element.getAnnotation(sub);`.

Comment: @Sweeper@Stephen C
The code really works fine on JDK 1.8. It's really time to upgrade to Java 8.
Thank you very much.